# Why can't I overwrite my style.css on my localhost?

Tags: css

I have designed my website with css now, but I have a big problem:
When I save my style.css and upload it to my localhost server, it doesn't overwrite my previous.
So it is not possible to change anything.
The code itself works.

I hope you can help me.

Daniel.

Comment: The css file is cached in the browser. You need to use some cachebusting technique. This could give you ideas: https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/

Of course if you just develop locally you can also just do a hard reload of the browser to download cached items.

Comment: Work now. I did a hard refresh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should clean your browser cache plus check that using the same classes or ids for the new file with the same CSS file and take care of any ! important css .